# schedule tasks to run

Tags: c#, vbscript

I have 5 console applications I would like to run in 5 different daytime.
I can add them all in the task scheduler but I wish to make a script schedule them instead.

Could someone help me please ?

Comment: Do you want a script that runs your applications at specified times or do you want a script that creates your scheduled tasks in the regular windows scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

Googled... and found just in 2 minutes. Keywords: "Schedule task C#"

--from http://geekswithblogs.net/rgupta/archive/2008/11/18/schedule-a-task-using-c-code.aspx

`DateTime taskTime = DateTime.Now;
timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(Update), null, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(21 * 60 (taskTime.Hour * 60 + taskTime.Minute)), 
TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));`

An advanced one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2478/C-Scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to develop a windows service with a timer object to call your programs at specified intervals.

Answer (score 0):

You can create windows service and use Quartz.NET to schedule jobs.

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/